# Transform Get from API in async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core

I'm trying to transform my action get all users to async but when I run, show me, for example, 2 users but without a name, email, etc. I know that those fields exist because I can see them in 'show', 'edit' and 'delete'.

**This is my code:**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<User> users = null;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5000/api/");
        //HTTP GET
        var responseTask = client.GetAsync("users/");
        responseTask.Wait();

        var result = responseTask.Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<User>>();
            readTask.Wait();

            users = readTask.Result;
        }
        else //web api sent error response 
        {
            //log response status here..

            users = Enumerable.Empty<User>();

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error. Please contact administrator.");
        }
    }
return View(users);
}
```

**What I am trying to transform in async:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    IEnumerable<User> users = null;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5000/api/");
        //HTTP GET
        var response = await client.GetAsync("users/");


        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var resulString = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            users = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<User>>(resulString);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error. Please contact administrator.");
        }
    }
    return View(users);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Please add some examples of `resulString`. Are any exceptions being thrown?

Comment: The issue is, when i run show me 1 table but the fields with name, email are empty but the edit and delete exists, it means they exists but not visible or something i dont know. `resultString` return null same as users and response return status 200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should call ReadAsStringAsync instead of ReadAsStreamAsync

```
var resulString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
users = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<User>>(resulString);
```

Comment: hmm but if i do that after in `users = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<User>>(resulString);` give this error `cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'`

Comment: you are right, use Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<User>>(resulString) this for deserialize

Comment: but if i want use await in this line how i do that? it works :)

Comment: this line does't any IO or  parallel operation so there is no need to use await